# Automatically paste copied text from browser into terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, browser, copy, paste

I was wondering if it's possible to automatically paste copied text from browser (Firefox) into terminal? (Linux)

When working with something like a tutorial in Github the auto command text copy function is great but would be even more efficient if it automatically pastes into the terminal and runs the command.

Comment: Are you asking as a web developer, or as a user? (If the former, you're asking for something incredibly dangerous. If the latter, IMHO trying to be "more efficient" kinda misses the whole point of a _tutorial_.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlikely.

Firstly what you copy from a tutorial is just text. To automatically run it on paste the text needs to contain a carriage return. It doesn't, so the utility needs to add it. If it's done automatically, it will affect every piece of text you copy, not only shell commands - how'd it tell the difference?

Secondly you'd need to link the browser process and the shell process together in a way that events in one directly affect the other. Check `ps -ef` when your Firefox is running - how to identify the appropriate process to link? How about if you have multiple shell instances running - how would the appropriate process be identified?

*Most important* are however the severe security implications **user1686** brought up in his comment.